# Listview error first and last item

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a `ListView`, I create a layout with `EditText` and `Button`, the problem is when I write in the first item of the list, automatically the last item of the list set same information. I'm using in my `ViewHolder` adapter.

Example of my Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) { 
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lst_autocomplete, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.direction = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
            holder.information= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtInformation);
            holder.tag = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTag);
            holder.check= (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkCheck);
            holder.product = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProduct);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        CustomAdapter adapter  = new CustomAdapter(context, cutom_list.lst_product);

        holder.direction.setAdapter(adapter);
        holder.direction.setThreshold(1);

        holder.direction.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Global list= (Global) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                holder.direction.setText(list.getDesc());
                holder.information.setText(list.getUbi());
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should provide some code from your adapter.

Comment: @redead Hello, edited question and part of my code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line: `CustomAdapter adapter  = new CustomAdapter(context, cutom_list.lst_product);`?

Comment: @redead Sending adapter to AutocompleteTextView

Comment: Could you provide additional code when you update your adapters data set?